# How to know if a puppeteer instance already exists?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I have multiple puppeteer scripts which I would like to run simultaneously, till now I was using multiple browsers for each script but now I want to use only one browser with the multiple scripts running concurrently in different pages.

My aim is to connect to the puppeteer instance if one already exists or create one if it doesn't exist (this newly created one will also be used by my other scripts).

How can I achieve this? I am aware of `puppeteer.connect()`.
I want to implement the following logic

```
Browser.js:
if(puppeteer instance exists){
  return browser.wsEndpoint()
} else {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  return browser.wsEndpoint();
}
```

Inside my script files:

```
puppeteer.connect(call browser.js);
```

This way whenever I call browser.js I will always get a puppeteer instance.

Answer (score 0):

While usually bad practice, the best way to tackle your problem might be with a global variable.

Use the following code:

global.browser = await puppeteer.launch(opts);

Then just use browser.whateveryoulike anywhere else in your code